# how to create a folder and put a txt file into it in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I make a code then ask the user where he wants to put a text file created from an excel sheet.
if the selected folder is named `formatted file`, then a file should create. if the folder `formatted file` doesn't exist, the code should create a file named `formatted Files` and then create the text file in it.
the text file contains 4 columns of data from excel.
For now, the folder is created in the right place. the code is update with the correct solution.

if there's a way to simplify my code let me know!!

Here's my actual code:

```
       Sub register_formated_data()
    '
    ' register_formated_data Macro
    '
    Dim order As Object
    Dim Folder As Object
    Dim Folder_path As String
    Dim lastrow As Long

    Dim fSo As Object
    Dim myFile As Object

    FolderName = "Formated Files"
    Filename = "formated" & Right(Sheets(8).Cells(12, 6).Value, InStr(File_path, "\"))

    Dim FL As String ' FL is for file location

    Sheets(8).Cells(12, 12).Value = ""

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)   '
        .Title = "Select where you want the folder to be"  'Open the file explorer
        .InitialFileName = ThisWorkbook.path & "\"         'for you to select
        .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewDetails            'the file you want
        .AllowMultiSelect = True                           'to add the txt file
        .Show                                              '

        On Error GoTo PROC_EXIT
        If Not .SelectedItems(1) = vbNullString Then FL = .SelectedItems(1)

    End With

    Sheets(8).Cells(12, 12).Value = FL

    Folder_path = FL + "\" + FolderName

Set fSo = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If Not fSo.FolderExists(Folder_path) Then
    fSo.CreateFolder (Folder_path)
    If fSo.FolderExists(Folder_path) Then
        Set fSo = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set myFile = fSo.CreateTextFile(Folder_path + "\" + Filename, True)

        myFile.WriteLine "Error"

        myFile.Close
        Set fSo = Nothing
    End If
Else
    If fSo.FolderExists(Folder_path) Then
    Set fSo = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set myFile = fSo.CreateTextFile(Folder_path + "\" + Filename, True)

    myFile.WriteLine "Error"

    myFile.Close
    Set fSo = Nothing
    End If
End If


PROC_EXIT:
End Sub
```

Comment: Turn off your line `On Error GoTo PROC_EXIT` and then run. What is the specific error that you get?

Comment: @urdearboyi get error'58' the folder exist already ... but i don'tsee it... and the msgbox FL give me a string, the location where the file should be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `FL` is picked using a FileDialog, it seems you are trying to create folder FL when it already exists.

Using 
`fSo.CreateFolder(FL).Name = FolderName` 
is equivalent to

`folder = fSo.CreateFolder(FL)
 folder.Name = FolderName`

So you need to substitute it by `fSo.CreateFolder(FolderName)`.

The corrected code block is then:

```
Set fSo = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If Not fSo.FolderExists(Folder_path) Then
    fSo.CreateFolder(Folder_path)          
    If fSo.FolderExists(Folder_path) Then
        Set fSo = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set myFile = fSo.CreateTextFile(Folder_path + "\" + Filename, True)

        myFile.WriteLine "Error"

        myFile.Close
        Set fSo = Nothing
    End If
End If
```

Comment: i did substitute `fso.CreateFolder(FL).Name = FolderName` by `fSo.CreateFolder(FolderName)`. the result is the creation of the folder (yay) but it's not in the good folder. (i.e. it should be in ./folderA/folderB/Formated file but istead it's in ./FolderA/Formated file )